# Adding multiple toggle switchers to a form

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle

I wanted to change the border color of the #bounds to green when the toggle is on but now when there are more than one switch toggle it changes the first toggle color when tapping on the others.

I just want to be able to make multiple toggles and maintaine the first toggle behivor for green = on and gray = off.

```js
$("input:radio").click(function(ev) {
  if (ev.currentTarget.value == "1") {
    $('#switchtoggle').removeClass('gray');
    $('#switchtoggle').addClass('green');

  } else if (ev.currentTarget.value == "0") {
    $('#switchtoggle').addClass('gray');
    $('#switchtoggle').removeClass('green');

  }
});
```

```css
#switchtoggle {
  padding: 2px;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  border-radius: 2em;
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
  color: transparent;
  border: 3px solid #e8e8e8;
}

#switchtoggle.active {
  border-color: #7FC6A6;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#switchtoggle label {
  float: left;
  width: 3.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  margin: 0;
}

#switchtoggle label span {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  background: #7FC6A6;
  width: 1.75em;
  height: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: 350ms all;
  float: left;
}

#switchtoggle label input {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2.0em;
  height: 1.25em;
  opacity: 0;
}

#switchtoggle label input.off:checked+span {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  color: transparent;
  margin-left: 1.75em;
}

#switchtoggle label input.off:checked {
  display: none;
}

#switchtoggle label input.on:checked+span {
  background: #7FC6A6;
  color: transparent;
  border-radius: 1em;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
}

#switchtoggle label input.on:checked {
  display: none;
}

.switchtoggle.gray {
  border: 3px solid #e8e8e8 !important;
}

.switchtoggle.green {
  border: 3px solid #7FC6A6 !important;
}

#switchtoggle label input.off:checked+#switchtoggle {
  border: 3px solid #e8e8e8 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
NOFITICATIONS?<br>
<div id="switchtoggle" class="switchtoggle green">
  <label>
<input class="on" type="radio" name="notifications" value="1" checked>         
<input class="off" type="radio" name="notifications" value="0">
<span></span>
</label>
</div>
<br><br><br> EMAIL?
<br>
<div id="switchtoggle" class="switchtoggle gray">
  <label>
<input class="on" type="radio" name="emails" value="1">         
<input class="off" type="radio" name="emails" value="0" checked>
<span></span>
</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JavaScript currently tries to add and remove the green/gray class from an element with the ID switchtoggle. As the first occurrence is the fist toggle element, it switched that.

To switch the .switchtoggle element of the clicked radio input, search for the next parent of the clicked checkbox (with the jQuery function parents()) which has the class .switchtoggle and remove/add the class there:

```js
$("input:radio").click(function(ev) {
  var label = $(ev.target).parents('.switchtoggle');
  if (ev.currentTarget.value == "1") {
    label.removeClass('gray');
    label.addClass('green');

  } else if (ev.currentTarget.value == "0") {
    label.addClass('gray');
    label.removeClass('green');

  }
});
```

```css
#switchtoggle {
  padding: 2px;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  border-radius: 2em;
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
  color: transparent;
  border: 3px solid #e8e8e8;
}

#switchtoggle.active {
  border-color: #7FC6A6;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#switchtoggle label {
  float: left;
  width: 3.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  margin: 0;
}

#switchtoggle label span {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  background: #7FC6A6;
  width: 1.75em;
  height: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: 350ms all;
  float: left;
}

#switchtoggle label input {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2.0em;
  height: 1.25em;
  opacity: 0;
}

#switchtoggle label input.off:checked+span {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  color: transparent;
  margin-left: 1.75em;
}

#switchtoggle label input.off:checked {
  display: none;
}

#switchtoggle label input.on:checked+span {
  background: #7FC6A6;
  color: transparent;
  border-radius: 1em;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
}

#switchtoggle label input.on:checked {
  display: none;
}

.switchtoggle.gray {
  border: 3px solid #e8e8e8 !important;
}

.switchtoggle.green {
  border: 3px solid #7FC6A6 !important;
}

#switchtoggle label input.off:checked+#switchtoggle {
  border: 3px solid #e8e8e8 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
NOFITICATIONS?<br>
<div id="switchtoggle" class="switchtoggle green">
  <label>
<input class="on" type="radio" name="notifications" value="1" checked>         
<input class="off" type="radio" name="notifications" value="0">
<span></span>
</label>
</div>
<br><br><br> EMAIL?
<br>
<div id="switchtoggle" class="switchtoggle gray">
  <label>
<input class="on" type="radio" name="emails" value="1">         
<input class="off" type="radio" name="emails" value="0" checked>
<span></span>
</label>
</div>
```